# Not showing message box in asp.net c# using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(); to show a message in asp.net C#

If i Write below code then its working

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowMessage", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", "Record Saved"));
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", ex.Message.ToString()));
```

**But if I write**

```
string Result = objChap.Insert();
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", Result));
```

then its not working means that messagebox in not displaying

My full code is

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            objChap.FK_SemesterID = Convert.ToDecimal(drplstSem.SelectedValue);
            objChap.FK_SubjectID = Convert.ToDecimal(drplstSub.SelectedValue);
            objChap.ChapterName= txtChap.Text;
            objChap.ChapterSName = txtChapShortName.Text;
            objChap.Remarks = txtRemarks.Text;
            objChap.Dta_User = Global.Dta_User;
            objChap.Dta_Users = Global.Dta_User;


            string Result = objChap.Insert();
            if (Result == "1")
            {

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowMessage", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", "Record Saved"));

            }
            else
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error1", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", Result));



            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", ex.Message.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've checked your script - it works

Comment: @voo but at my side its not working

Comment: Maybe the string contains quotes, breaking the script. Can you debug and see what's the value of `Result`?

Comment: Is Javascript alert that is not displaying the one generated by script with key `ShowMessage` or `Error1`?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Error is:" Error : Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ChapterSName', table 'tablename'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. " here i know what is error but why messagebox is not displaying

Comment: @IvanG alert that is not displaying the one generated by script with key is Error1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the string contains single quotes, it breaks the script since single quotes are also used to wrap the value passed to `alert()`.

To overcome this, escape the quotes:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error1", 
    string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", 
    Result.Replace("'", "\\'")));
```

Comment: I can't express how I'm feeling after reading this answer! I had left the hope of my code getting executed successfully!!! 
Thanks a lot. I wish I could upvote it 100 times...

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful lol, sometimes the small things are easy to miss... :)

Answer (score 0):

The above solution didn't work for me, but my situation is just slightly different.

This works fine:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSscript", "alert('this is a test');", true);
```

This does not:

```
String MetaJS = Convert.ToString(aList["JavaScript"].Value); //alert('this is a test'); 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MetaScript", MetaJS, true);
```

And this does not:

```
String MetaJS = Convert.ToString(aList["JavaScript"].Value); //alert('this is a test'); 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MetaScript", string.Format("{0}", MetaJS.Replace("'", "\\'")), true);
```